# How can I debug asp pages using IE Developer Tools?

Tags: debugging, asp-classic

I have an asp application. Is it possible to debug vb.net code embedded in the asp page using Internet Explorer?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it Classic ASP(VBScript) application or VB.NET application? One you can debug using VS and other you can debug only using response.write lines inside your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is no

You've tagged this question as Classic ASP but you mention vb.net which is used in asp.net.  Anyway, both Classic ASP and ASP.net are server side technologies, and IE Developer tools are used for debugging client side code (Javascript, CSS, HTML etc)

To debug your VB.net code you'll probably need Visual Studio (or Visual Web Developer, which is a free, cut down version of Visual Studio)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use VS 2012 to debug and attached to the process, but could not hit the breakpoint as there was no symbols...

Comment: If all else fails you may get an error page (the Yellow Screen of Death) which pinpoint where the problem is.